# PCRE - можно ли в один карман положить значения разных кусков строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

К примеру есть строка

```
<div>
    Дата прибытия: <input type="text" value="14.11.2016" />
</div>
<div>
    Склад получения: <input type="text" value="Москва, ул. Тратата, 37" />
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то в один карман с помощью `preg_math()` положить такой текст `Дата прибытия: 14.11.2016`?

Еще пока не весь PCRE изучил.

Comment: А что такое "карман" ? Если вы про переменные - то нет - в две отдельные и потом объединять. либо preg_replace убрать все лишнее и оставить только эту строку

Comment: @Mike карман  - подмаска - matches - результаты поиска http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Comment: В одну без лишнего текста в середине невозможно. Да  и не требуется это. Всегда можно два группы захвата объединить после match

Comment: @JeanClaude, а где вы там нашли термин "карман"? Формулируйте мысли ясней чтобы вас поняли, тут программисты, а не политики :) Я понял, например, что у вас проблема объединить две группы захвата в одну переменную после отработки preg_match...

Comment: @PinkTux Котеров (многим известная книга "PHP 7" Дмитрий Котеров) использует термин карман. В инете такой термин также встречается часто.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, есть общепринятая терминология, а есть какая-то местечковая отсебятина. Последней лучше не пользоваться. Впрочем, вам, конечно, видней, с высоты вашего опыта :)

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Это невозможно.
Сохраняющая группировка (карман) содержит внутри себя **непрерывную** последовательность из текста, к которому было применено регулярное выражение.

Делайте несколько группировок (карманов) и объединяйте их средствами PHP для достижения необходимого результата.